# Access express session value on another page - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I want to set a session value on `app.get('/login', ())` and later retrieve that value on home page, but I am not getting that value on any other page apart from the login page.

Is this how express-session works or is there anything wrong from my side?

```
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
    secret: 'firstsession',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    req.session.user = "abc";
    req.session.save();
    res.send('test');
})

app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session) // this does not give the value user = "abc";
    res.send('test');
})
```

Comment: the code looks ok, `req.session.save()` is an async function, but save is automatically called if session variable is changed so that is optional one. Also, I replicated the example and can confirm that session works as expected. How are you calling the `/dashboard` route? after login route? with same browser window?

Comment: can confirm your code sample works properly

Comment: im using angular7 on the frontend.. url is http://localhost:4200 and node is listening on 3000..could that be the issue ?

Comment: if u just paste the code in .js file and run it works ..but when the request comes from localhost:4200 then it doesnt work as expected @KrzysztofKrzeszewski

Comment: it does work for me tho

Comment: doesnt work when request is sent from angular otherwise it works for me anyways

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the user you need write **req.session.user**